# Publication List Not Showing Up In Send Definition

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I have two empty Publication Lists in my ET account and want to use them in Send Definitions linked to a Data Extension.  The Publication Lists are not showing up when I try to link a Publication list to a Data Extension in the Send Definition.  Please help.

Comment: Can you tell what kind of account you have (enterprise 2.0, core, etc.?)

Comment: Also, can you tell me if you have EVER seen publication lists show up in UI sends within your account?

Answer (score 1):

The Publication Lists not showing up was easily solved by calling ExactTarget customer service.  While on the user side, there's no way to tell what was wrong, the Publication Lists were made visible by the tech.  Thanks!